# Include doesn't work

Tags: php

This is not including the file 'header.html':

```
<?php  
    include 'includes/header.html'; 
    $pageTitle = 'Регистрация';
?>
```

When I open the page is shows the code.

Comment: Is the page a `.php` page? Do you have a webserver active and properly configured? How are you accessing the page? We need some more infos

Comment: The page is .php. I have local webserver. I use "Wamp".

Comment: I  will bet you that you're accessing it as `c:///file.php` rather than `http://localhost/file.php`.

Comment: file:///C:/wamp/www/sustezanie_sait/registraciya.php

Comment: @CodeGodie *"When I open the page is shows the code."* see my comment up there ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- yup I just realized that. deleted my comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *"I will bet you that you're accessing it as c:///file.php rather than http://localhost/file.php. – Fred -ii- 2 mins ago"*

and OP

> *"file:///C:/wamp/www/sustezanie_sait/registraciya.php – Tolga Kantarov 1 min ago"*

There you go. I was right.

You need to access your file as `http://localhost/file.php` and not as `c:///file.php`

That is the reason why it's showing you "code" instead of being parsed.

A web browser will not parse PHP directives if accessed like that, not like an `.html` file where `c:///file.html` will indeed show HTML code.

Comment: In most of the cases @Fred-ii- is right.. :) awesome job men...keep it up.. :)

Comment: @GaganUpadhyay Thanks :-) *Cheers*

Comment: It works! Thanks! But why it worked normaly 2 days and it decided to stop

Comment: @TolgaKantarov You're welcome. Could be something interfering with your OS. You may either have to restart your PC, or restart all services. A green light will tell you if everything is running.

Comment: @devpro *Spidey sense tingled* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Nice answer :)